# method with dictionary parameter

Tags: c#, dictionary, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Please tell me or indicate the correct way to solve this problem, I have no experience yet and it is very difficult to understand how to solve this problem. I would be grateful for any help.

My Form class should only contain a single public method:

```
class Form
{
    public void FillForm(Dictionary<string, string> values)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

which will fill this form (and in fact, any similarly implemented form) with values based only on fieldname-value pairs stored in the dictionary.

[And I have such a xpath to fill out a form using a dictionary, it must be one for the whole task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLr1J.png)

the form has multiple fields

1. Text with a question
2. Name
3. Email
4. contact phone
5. location
6. Age

Comment: why do you have to use a dictionary to hold the information?

Comment: Use model instead of dictionary.

Comment: @ImirHoxha a dictionary is needed in order to fill in the fields for sending a question on the site

Comment: @HirenPatel on assignment I need a dictionary

Comment: @dantalion I know what dictionary is used for, but you don't seem to grasp it. You have to spend some time in understanding it.
You don't need a dictionary in this case as you are going to hold information only for one user who posts one question, unless you are accumulating all questions

Comment: check my answer below where it says Edit. You will have to use a string and a class in the dictionary to hold your information. Question has to be unique otherwise you will run into an error with Dictioary object

Comment: @ImirHoxha I in no way wanted to tell you what a dictionary is, to complete the task I need a dictionary to which I will bind one xpath element (universal for fields) with which I can fill each field with values from the dictionary as much as possible.

Comment: there you have it. Third option added, but I wouldn't use it in my code that way.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary contains key-value pairs. Key has to be unique. So in this case dictionary is not a good way to go.

You will have to construct a domain model first:

```
//This will hold your user information
public class UserInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

//this other class is called a viewmodel which combains your user and the question posed by the user
public class FormData
{
    public UserInfo user { get; set; }
    public string question { get; set; }
}

//this class is your public facing interface which will interact with the user/front-end form

public class Questionaire
{
    FormData _data; 
    public void FillForm(FormData data)
    {
        //do whatever you want with the data
        //save to database, send by email, whatever
        _data = data;
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

//this is how you use it to collect data from the user
            Questionaire questionaire = new Questionaire();
            questionaire.FillForm(new FormData
            {
                question = "your question goes here",
                user = new UserInfo
                {
                    Name = "YourName",
                    Age = 20,
                    Email = "someemail",
                    Location = "yourlocation",
                    Phone = "0123665555"
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

---

**Option 2 (since you insist in using dictionary):**

```
    public class UserInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }


        Dictionary<string, UserInfo> _values;
        public void FillForm(Dictionary<string, UserInfo> values)
        {
            _values = values;
        }


//You call it like this:
            Dictionary<string, UserInfo> dic = new Dictionary<string, UserInfo>();
            dic.Add("question1", new UserInfo { Age = 20, Name = "Name1" });
            dic.Add("question2", new UserInfo { Age = 20, Name = "Name2" });

            Form form = new Form();
            form.FillForm(dic);
```

---

**Option 3 but this is not the way to go:**

```
public class Form2
{
    Dictionary<string, string> _values;
    public void FillForm(Dictionary<string, string> values)
    {
        _values = values;
    }
}


Dictionary<string, string> user1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
user1.Add("question1", "Users question goes here");
user1.Add("Name", "name1");
user1.Add("Age", "age");
            //...
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.FillForm(user1);
```